# WP7 how to wipe the device?

Tags: c#, silverlight, security, windows-phone-7

i'm creating a silverlight app and just want to know if there is a way to wipe a WP7 mango device in code?

Comment: Why on earth would your application need this kind of privilege?

Comment: There is a reason why they run all the apps in sandbox mode... for people like you trying to do stuff like that.

Comment: We could tell you but then Microsoft would have to ....

Answer (score 4):

Since resetting the phone erases all the installed applications I'm pretty much sure that this is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you work for an OEM which manufactures windows phones, this will not be possible.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a rooted device can be wiped programmatically. Otherwise, You can wipe only the data present in the Isolated Storage of the application. Not the data belonging to the other applications. This is called sandboxing.  I would suggest you to read the [Windows phone 7 security model](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=8842). The 4 chambers in WP7 Security model , and how the isolation is maintained between these 4 layers.